# ms access replication id as foreign key

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am currently "forced" to create a database in ms access 2007.

Due to replication issues i have decided to use autonumber as ReplicationID for my Users table.

On my venues table i would like to use this id as the user created.

I have tried to use the userID in textboxes accross the main form, but it outputs

```
{guid {BF40D0A0-A1F3-4C98-A9B6-D9D075F0BBA3}}
```

and when using this value to insert into my Venues table, it generates a new ReplicationID.

Am i missing some setting where it will use the GUID provided, or do you have any other suggestion.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

I don't pretend to understand replication in Access.  However the two best resources are

- [Subject: INFO: Replication and
  GUIDs, the Good, the Bad, and the
  Ugly](http://www.trigeminal.com/usenet/usenet011.asp?1033)  Basically don't use GUID as
  a primary key.
- [Jet Replication Wiki](http://www.dfenton.com/DFA/Replication/)  David Fenton has stated it would
  be fine if those without experience
  created sections for issues they
  wanted explained.

Answer (score 0):

OK i found it. What happened was that you cannot insert a guid string in ms access, you have to use the actual object. Then all was fine.

dont use StringFromGUID/GUIDFromString, just insert the object as is and all is well.

Any questions and i will gladly explain X-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't expose autonumber values to users, especially of the GUID flavour!

Comment: I would like to use it as a foreign key in another table, so storing it in a hidden field. The user will not see the GUID.

Comment: But why store it in a hidden field. Sounds crazy to me. No doubt that's the way Access Forms work, then ;)